# I try to upgrade my react native project from 0.57.4 to 0.58.6, but it doesn't work

Tags: react-native, gradle, jestjs, babel-jest

Here are the dependencies of my package.json :

```
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "react": "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728",
    "react-native": "0.57.4",
    "react-navigation": "^3.2.3",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.49.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.0-alpha.8af6728"
  },
```

When I run the command npm, it tells me that I have to run npm audit fix :

```
found 69 low severity vulnerabilities in 37658 scanned packages
  run `npm audit fix` to fix 6 of them.
  63 vulnerabilities require semver-major dependency updates.
```

And i have this in the list :

```
# Run  npm install jest@24.3.1  to resolve 62 vulnerabilities
SEMVER WARNING: Recommended action is a potentially breaking change
...
# Run  npm install react-native@0.58.6  to resolve 2 vulnerabilities
...
# Run  npm install babel-jest@24.3.1  to resolve 1 vulnerability
SEMVER WARNING: Recommended action is a potentially breaking change
```

I use gradle 4.8 and openjdk 11.0.1

When i run react-native run-android, i get an error...

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible 
with Gradle 5.0.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html
#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 8s
29 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 22 up-to-date
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and 
have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Command failed: gradlew.bat installDebug

Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat installDebug
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:611:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:629:13)
    at runOnAllDevices (D:\WORKSPACES_REACT_NATIVE\LG\node_modules\react- 
    native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:299:19)
    at buildAndRun (D:\WORKSPACES_REACT_NATIVE\LG\node_modules\react- 
   native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:135:12)
    at isPackagerRunning.then.result 
   (D:\WORKSPACES_REACT_NATIVE\LG\node_modules\react-native\local- 
   cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:65:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Comment: What changes did you make as part of your upgrade process?

Comment: npm install react-native@0.58.6

Comment: @L.G I tried npm install react-native@0.58.6 after that it is giving me errors